# Sqlcmd query in mutliple database "Unexpected argument"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlcmd

I have an SQL query which I need to run on multiple instances through one request.

```
Use Extracts
DECLARE @RunDate DATETIME;
DECLARE @WeeklyRunDate DATETIME;
SET @RunDate = '2016/08/31'
SET @WeeklyRunDate = (select DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, @RunDate)-1), @RunDate))
Update Extracts..Processlastruns
Set Proclastrunsystemdate =@WeeklyRunDate , proclastwritesystemdate =@WeeklyRunDate
Where Procrunid in(select Procrunid From Extracts..Processruns Where Procrunenabled ='1' and Procrunfreqdaycount ='7')
Update Extracts..Processlastruns
Set Proclastrunsystemdate =@RunDate , proclastwritesystemdate =@RunDate
Where Procrunid in(select Procrunid From Extracts..Processruns Where Procrunenabled ='1' and Procrunfreqdaycount ='1')
```

I use that query but it isn't working. I'm catching "Unexpected argument"

```
sqlcmd -S 192.168.0.1 -U sa -P test1234 
"Use Extracts DECLARE @RunDate DATETIME; DECLARE @WeeklyRunDate DATETIME; SET @RunDate = '2016/08/31' SET @WeeklyRunDate = (select DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, @RunDate)-1), @RunDate)) Update Extracts..Processlastruns Set Proclastrunsystemdate =@WeeklyRunDate , proclastwritesystemdate =@WeeklyRunDate Where Procrunid in(select Procrunid From Extracts..Processruns Where Procrunenabled ='1' and Procrunfreqdaycount ='7') Update Extracts..Processlastruns Set Proclastrunsystemdate =@RunDate proclastwritesystemdate =@RunDate Where Procrunid in(select Procrunid From Extracts..Processruns Where Procrunenabled ='1' and Procrunfreqdaycount ='1')" -o extract.csv -s"," -w 700
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to add the switch `-Q` [Microsoft sqlcmd Utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx)

```
sqlcmd -S 192.168.0.1 -U sa -P test1234 -Q "your SQL" -o extract.csv -s"," -w 700
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change** Update Extracts..Processlastruns **To** Update Extracts.Processlastruns,
also there some place where your query have **'..'** in table prefix

Comment: No, it doesnt' help because if i run that query in Management Studio it works well. But when i try to make Sqlcmd query it make an error. I think something in syntax of sqlcmd.